# Board game boxes

Tags: storage, game-development

It seems like most commercial board games come in the same kinds of boxes.  Where can you buy such boxes (without labels already on them)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably need to contact a boardgame manufacturer, or prototyping service. Would probably run you about $2 a box.

- [Board Game Design](http://www.boardgamedesign.com/pages/go_shopping_2012/boxes_combined.htm)
- [Print and Play productions](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/47269/item/1276018#item1276018)
- [Speilmaterial.de](http://www.spielematerial.de/en/game-components/game-boxes.html)

Answer (score 1):

For the US, check the Container Store. They certainly have simple boxes that work for prototypes.