# Where can I find a printer for a budget game board?

Tags: custom-game-pieces, game-development

I'm trying to get a board printed for a game I'm making. Are there any companies/websites that can provide this service relatively cheaply?

Ideally, each board would cost $5 or less. The material only needs to last long enough for people to understand how the game works, and this is only for small scale production and sale of 100 units or so.

The board is a two-sided board for a card-based game, and it can either be one foldable piece or two pieces. The cards will be [poker size](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/13877/), and the board should be at minimum six card slots across in dimension, meaning at least 381mm wide.

Comment: How do you define 'cheap'?  Would a $500 3d printer be cheap? Do you want to spend under $5?  Also, is this for proof of concept or for mass production?

Comment: Cheap is <$5 a board ideally, the design is very simple and the material only needs to last long enough for people to understand how the game works. The purpose is for small scale production and sale, only about 100 units or so
Thanks!

Comment: @user6802 I've made a guess at the dimensions you mean, but it seems [there is not only one poker size](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/14238/5573), so "six poker cards wide" is not a specific measurement. If the measurement's important (it might be!) I advise you to mention a specific measurement. Also, bear in mind it should probably be a couple of centimetres wider than the cards, since some padding would be helpful.

Comment: Why not submit your game to a publisher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this site , they can produce a lot of material for board game and after you can even use their online store for the distribution.

https://www.thegamecrafter.com/

Answer (score 1):

Taken from an answer to another question ([Board game boxes](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/board-game-boxes))...

http://www.boardgamedesign.com/pages/goshopping.htm

I'm behind a firewall and can't find other links, but this at least seems like a start.