# Where can I get good-quality boxes of custom sizes, so I can store my board games compactly?

Tags: storage, dixit

I want to store Dixit Odyssey + another Dixit expansion in a box.
The original Dixit boxes are too big. Not convenient for transportation...

As I've searched around, and didn't find any suitable box, **I was thinking of getting a box with the dimensions of my choosing**. This would be helpful for many other games as well.

Are there specialized products for this? Custom-sized boxes, eventually with the option of defining separators inside of the box?

Which box types and dimensions should I be looking for to store and transport expansion sets of Dixit cards?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking about shopping recommendations and is asking opinion based questions about what to get.

Comment: @JoeW: How is this off-topic? I'm looking for options to store my board games... I've edited my answer to ask for products and not stores.

Comment: I will still say this is off topic as it is not much different then asking for game recommendations in my opinion as mostly likely you are going to get opinion based answers for this question.

Comment: @JoeW I would disagree that it is like a game-rec, since those are for asking about games to play for which there are several different answers all of which could be perfectly valid. This is asking about a specific type of product for a specific game, with fairly specific requirements. That should be answerable with examples of how it meets the requirements

Comment: I agree with @JoeW https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ but this can be made objective.

Comment: I bag my games and place them together in a plastic tote to maximize the number of games I keep in my car

Comment: @diego The problem really comes down to what one person may say is a quality container another might say is garbage, a lot will depend on the individual person.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Board game boxes](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/board-game-boxes)

Comment: @SQB Not a duplicate, as the linked question asks to buy standard, existing boxes and this question asks for custom boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Dixit expansions come in boxes of size 8.1 x 3 x 12.7 cm. The cards from the base set, Journey or Odyssey should fit in one of those exact same boxes. Get a box for each expansion that you own. You could make your own boxes, from sheets of cardboard using a box template like this one. You'll want to use 250 grams paper (g/m2, see [grammage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammage)).

[image: template generator]

Just put your dimensions into a [template generator](http://www.templatemaker.nl/index.php?template=cardbox&lang=en).

The voting cards can go into a small bag, and you don't really need the bunnies and scoring track. Bring pen and paper.

Comment: The Dixit expansion box doesn't work for me because I'm trying to pack Dixit Odyssey which board is ~15x26cm. The template generator is a very nice idea. Thanks.

Comment: If anyone knows the proper units of measurement for US standards, please by all means do edit them into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you have Dixit Odyssey (abbreviated as DO from now on), I thought I'd share my solution. We have many card games (Bang, Fluxx, Saboteurs, etc) and DO. For transportation I've found it works well if I take the plastic inset (tray?) out of DO, and the resulting space is more than enough for all games. Of course each deck needs to be wrapped in a rubber band to avoid mixing, but the sturdy cardboard box of DO makes it easy to carry all our games.

This of course doesn't solve the problem if the problem is the DO box being too big, but maybe you can use the space inside the box for other things too, in order to rationalize carrying such a large box.

Comment: Thank you, zovits. Indeed, I wanted the smaller pack possible, but that's also a good idea for reusing the box, if you have a lot of games.